# How to redirect all subfiles to main link in link directory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi i have link directories like this:

```
www.example.com/a-letter/a-1

www.example.com/a-letter/a-2

www.example.com/a-letter/a-3
```

i removed `a-letter` folder name from the link with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /a-letter/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^a-letter/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

and i want to redirect **all**  `a-1` `a-2` and `a-3` files under the `a-letter` folder to like below with one htaccess code

```
www.example.com/a-1
www.example.com/a-2
www.example.com/a-3
```

because i am using this codes for each link and i want to use one code for this. How can i specify the code for all files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^a-1$ /a-letter/a-1.html [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^a-2$ /a-letter/a-2.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I will be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Use: `RewriteRule ^(a-1|a-2)/?$ a-letter/$1.html [L,NC]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?a-letter/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/a-letter%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(a-1|a-2)/? /a-letter/$1.html [END]
```

An alternative would be that, if the name scheme is some thing like "a-.html":

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?a-letter/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/a-letter%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?a-(\d+)/? /a-letter/a-$1.html [END]
```

I personally do not use those `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` conditions ... Yes, the might formally prevent an internal server error. But what does that help?

1. Operating your site without those rules getting applied most likely does not make much sense.
2. You know whether you have installed the rewriting module or not. And you are most likely not going to change that frequently.

UPDATE:

In the comments you asked another question (again: please open a separate question in future for separate questions...). I would suggest such implementation:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^/?a-letter/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?comments/a/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/a-letter%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?a-(\d+)/? /a-letter/a-$1.html [END]

RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/a%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/? /comments/a/$1.html [END]
```

Your directives look fine, it might be that the issue you ran into is the order of directives. Always keep in mind that the directives are processed from top to bottom. Your last `RewriteRule` is very generic, it will match *anything* . Always keep more generic rules at the bottom, more precise exceptions further atop. And always *try* to modify rules such that they are less generic:

So instead of

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/? /comments/a/$1.html [END]
```

maybe something like that

```
RewriteRule ^/?(\w*)/? /comments/a/$1.html [END]
```

is possible?

Comment: i want to ask one more question. Now i have an another directory like `www.example.com/comments/a/word1` I removed comments/a/ section with 
htaccess. Under the 
a folder i have lots of words and i want to redirect these words like this www.example.com/word1`
I modified .htaccess code like this `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?comments/a/(.*)(/|\.html)?$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RequestCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/comments/a%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/? /comments/a/$1.html [END]` and i got the error `404 not found`. What can i do in this situation? I think i wrote `^/?(.*)/?` wrongly.

Comment: Well, do those files actually exist? So for example a file like `/comments/a/word1.html`?

Comment: And a general remark: it makes sense to ask separate questions separately. That allows for others to help and you can phrase and format your question such that it is easier to understand. You can add a reference to this question if you think it might help.

Comment: Yes these files already exists like `comments/a/word1.html` and i removed `comment/a/` section from the link with htaccess. I want to redirect `www.example.com/comments/a/word1.html` link to `www.example.com/word1.html` how can i do this. I will be grateful if you could help me. I modified the code like above but i got 404 page not found error.

Comment: I added an "UPDATE" to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help but `^/?(\w*)/?` not worked for me and i used `RewriteRule ^/?([^.?]+)$/? /comments/a/$1.html [END]` and worked.

Comment: OK, so your "words" do _not_ only contain letters, but also other stuff.

Comment: Yes in the original link it contains "-" like word-xyz-abc.html  .I could not think that not to mention it would cause such an error

Comment: No problem, you certainly always will have to adapt a given suggestion you get here to your specific needs. You cannot expect to simply copy&paste such suggestions. I would generally advise to always use a pattern that is as precise as possible. So maybe change `[^.?]` to something like `[\w-_]`? Also because I fail to understand the "?" inside the character group.